# User sessions between frontend and domain with JMS/ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, messaging

I have a web application which is hosted on a frontend application server. This frontend application communicates with the backend domain via JMS. When an end user issues a command this command is sent to the domain.

The backend server cannot fully trust the frontend application so authentication and authorization has to happen at the messaging endpoint of the domain. E.g.: frontend sends a login request, domain authenticates, sends back a session id which the frontend links to its own HTTP session. Subsequent requests to the domain will contain the session id.

What's a viable way to "tunnel" user sessions with JMS? I do not want to control access to the command queue, that's another issue. I'd like to not use the dumb approach of re-authenticating each request. Are there any established frameworks, protocols or patterns adequate for this task?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a single sign on mechanism.
I might be thinking in too simple terms (then please comment :) ) but what about this:
After your frontend authenticates to the domain and obtains its session id, you have the domain send that very same session id to the backend (which can store it a list of authenticated ids).
Now you can simply store the session id as a message property of your payload messages. Once your backend receives any messages, it reads the message property, checks the provided session id against known session ids and reacts accordingly.